# Issue with Bluetooth Low Energy indications on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently facing an issue with Bluetooth Low Energy on Android in a specific scenario.

I have a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device paired with my Android phone, which transmits a series of events, stored in the device's memory, to my Kotlin application. These events are transfered using indications over a specific characteristic, and each event is uniquely identified by a progressive ID.

The problem arises when I turn off Bluetooth on my Android phone during the transfer of events. Upon reconnection, after turning Bluetooth back on, event transfer resumes, but some IDs appear to have been lost.

Upon inspecting logs on both the device and the phone, I observed that the phone continues to send indication ACKs to the device for a short period (less than 1 second) even after Bluetooth has been turned off and my application has already received the  Bluetooth status `BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF`.

I have encountered this behavior on all the phones I have available for testing (Google Pixel 8, Samsung A52 and others..).
The same iOS application on iPhone, paired with the same BLE device, has no packet losses.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Android's Bluetooth stack that the teardown is executed in the wrong order. You should file a bug report to Android.